# Hide "_init" and "_fini" symbols in shared library

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries

I am creating a shared library and I noticed that by using `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` (together with `-fvisibility=hidden`) my library exports also `_init` and `_fini` symbols. If I use a an exported_symbols list (together with `-Wl,--version-script=<file_list>`) the lib only exports my functions, which is perfect.

Is it a way to use the first solution and only export my functions, without `_init` and `_fini`? thanks

Comment: I understand, but why are they not exported when I am using a symbols file? They are exported only when using the first method.

Comment: Global vars starting with _ belong to the implementation. Why mess with that?

Comment: @PSkocik To avoid polluting library's interface and improve performance of dynamic linker.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, the issue is not limited to `_init` and `_fini` - GNU toolchain exports other useless symbols by default e.g. `_edata`, etc. These symbols are indeed completely unnecessary (dynamic linker obtains pointers to ctors/dtors by different means).

I've recently reported the issue to [gcc-help](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2018-04/msg00097.html) and [Binutils](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2018-05/msg00012.html) lists. Reply in Bintools list was that although these symbols are indeed not used on Linux systems, removing them must be very careful and require a lot of testing and performance gains would be negligible. I didn't get answer in gcc-help (maybe makes sense to re-post in gcc developers list).

As a workaround, you can explicitly hide unwanted symbols via version script:

```
$ cat myapp.version
{
  global: XML_*; _INTERNAL_*;
  local: *;
};
$ cat Makefile
...
LDFLAGS += -Wl,--version-script=myapp.version
```

An example of this for Expat project can be found [here](https://github.com/libexpat/libexpat/issues/195#issue-317480051). One issue with this approach (apart from adding boilerplate to all projects instead of fixing it once in Binutils/GCC) is that it's hard to get it right with Autoconf.

Note that even if you use version script, you *still* need to compile with `-fvisibility=hidden` (it allows compiler to perform more aggressive optimizations on hidden symbols, whereas in version script's case compiler is unaware of what ends up being hidden).

Comment: thank you for your complete answer, I was wondering also why those useless symbols are not exported also when using an export script..